# How to get the value of a specific HTML element in a given HTML document or webpage (by URL)?

Tags: javascript, html, wpf, web, getelementbyid

I want to pass the url of a webpage containing a `<span id="spanID"> value </span>` tag to a method like `setTextBoxText(string url, string id)` which is written in a wpf application codeBehind (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`) and set the Text of a specific `TextBox` Control to the span value, without loading the webpage. (for Ex. tracking price of a product in amazon)

I prefer to execute JavaScript code to get value of html elements and set the content of wpf controls to the result of the js code (function)

something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string url = "https://websiteaddress.com/rest";
    setTextBoxText(url, "spanID");

    static void setTextBoxText(string url, string id)
    {
        // code to get document by given url
        txtPrice.Text = getHtmlElementValue(id);
    }

    string getHtmlElementValue(string id)
    {
        // what code should be written here?
        // any combination of js and c#?
        // var result = document.getElementById(id).textContent;
        // return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1)  to load the HTML content of an URL and then process the DOM object in a JavaScript like syntax by wrapping the response into a `mshtml.HTMLDocument` - requires reference to *Microsoft.mshtml.dll*:

```
private mshtml.HTMLDocument HtmlDocument { get; set; }

private async Task SetTextBoxTextAsync(string url, string id)
{
  await UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(url);
  var value = GetHtmlElementValueById(id);
  txtPrice.Text = value;
}

public async Task UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync(string url)
{
  using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
    byte[] response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    string httpResponseText = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    string htmlContent = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(httpResponseText);

    this.HtmlDocument = new HTMLDocument();
    (this.HtmlDocument as IHTMLDocument2).write(htmlContent);
  }
}

public string GetHtmlElementValueById(string elementId) 
  => this.HtmlDocument.getElementById(elementId).innerText;
```

Comment: How do i know if document is completely Loaded?
this line: `return this.HtmlDocument.getElementById(elementId).innerText;` threw System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I've posted a different implementation originally. I refactored this solution and forgot to adjust the method type. I have fixed the return type of `UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync`. This is also the method used to load the HTML document. You have to `await` this method. When `UpdateHtmlDocumentAsync` returns, the document (assigned to the property `HtmlDocument`) is loaded and ready to process.

Comment: Where is this exception thrown, inside `GetHtmlElementValueById`? The code works for me. `this.HtmlDocument`can return `null` if the URL doesn't resolve.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was accidentally observing the wrong event. I have changed the code to observe `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted` event instead. This should fix your exception.

Comment: Yes inside GetHtmlElementValueById. but url i entered is a valid webpage!

Comment: I have updated the example code. Please try again and tell me about your results.

Comment: No it doesn't work Yet :( 
The NullReferenceException still is bothering

Comment: Can you email a zip file of your working solution please? `mpourmorad@gmail.com`

Comment: I have implemented a version that works without the `WebBrowser` control. It appears like the control must actually be rendered in order to generate the document. The new implementation should work for you. It creates the DOM document manually from the response of a HTTP request to the provided URL. Note that in case and element is not found (e.g., by ID or tag name), the DOM methods return `null`. The code is tested.